# My ScrollView not working on button click properly in my mobile application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

when i click the button the scrollview work on time and next time not working

```
- (IBAction)scrollviewbtn:(id)sender {

     [_Scroll_View scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(_Scroll_View.frame.size.width, 0, self.Scroll_View.frame.size.width, self.Scroll_View.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: add some more info about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need check the frame of the button, if the button is out of it's superView, the touch event would not be responded.

Comment: - (IBAction)scrollviewbtn:(id)sender {
    
    if (self.Scroll_View.contentOffset.x <
        self.Scroll_View.contentSize.width - self.Scroll_View.frame.size.width){
        [self.Scroll_View setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.Scroll_View .contentOffset.x + self.Scroll_View .frame.size.width, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

i am solve this problem this code,

```
- (IBAction)scrollviewbtn:(id)sender {

    if (self.Scroll_View.contentOffset.x <
        self.Scroll_View.contentSize.width - self.Scroll_View.frame.size.width){
        [self.Scroll_View setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.Scroll_View .contentOffset.x + self.Scroll_View .frame.size.width, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}
```